# HTML login page in grails spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, grails, spring-security

I have grails application,

I want to use Angularjs and html for login, no gsp page.

I have installed grails 2.2.1 + spring-security-core:2.0-RC2 plugin.

default behavior gsp page for login.

But i wanted to add my custom html page and all the Authorization process by in Angularjs only.

so any suggestion, how to accomplish this task ?

I am total new baby to grails and spring security, so if possible give some links so i can go through to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the CSS and HTML to login.gsp, just maintain the form name and input fields with the same.